# How to use Fedora in WSL

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In WSL, the only available option is Ubuntu. However, if I want to use a Fedora what should I do. I understand the question had already been asked [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1126616/how-do-i-use-windows-10-wsl-with-fedora) but that was years ago. Any information would go a long way. Thanks

Comment: "In WSL, the only available option is Ubuntu." That's a surprise. I have been using Debian on WSL1 and WSL2 for years. Instructions from Microsoft dated September 15 2020 to install Fedora Remix on WSL are [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual)

Comment: Wow, I was unaware of this, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow the steps described on [Using Fedora 33 with Microsoft’s WSL2](https://fedoramagazine.org/wsl-fedora-33/) to add Fedora to WSL2, here is the essential steps:

1. Download Fedora from this  [github repo](https://github.com/fedora-cloud/docker-brew-fedora/tree/33/x86_64)
2. Uncompress the file, the result is `fedora-33.20210303-x86_64.tar`.
3. From cmd

```
wsl.exe --import Fedora-33 c:\distros\Fedora-33 $HOME\Downloads\fedora-33.20210303-x86_64.tar
```

4. Launch Fedora

```
wsl -d Fedora-33
```

Comment: I have already got Fedora running thanks to @Michael Harvey, however your answer seems great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also followed this but instead of downloading tar file as suggested by @GAD3R I used docker image of fedora.

To generate the tar file for fedora 39, use docker as follows:

```
docker run --name fedora39 fedora:39
docker export -o fedora-39-rootfs.tar fedora39
```

To import tar into WSL alongwith creation of dedicated directory for fedora:

```
mkdir $HOME\wsl\fedora
wsl --import fedora $HOME\wsl\fedora $HOME\Downloads\fedora-39-rootfs.tar
wsl -d fedora
```

I keep improving on my fedora WSL instance while documenting everything on this [github issue](https://github.com/king-11/dotrc/issues/3).